# Date Picker does not show current year

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a date picker to a input field.I is working fine in normal case when i does not pull data from database. But when i pull data from database date picker does not show current year. It show year 2099 by default. Please help if anybody have any idea.

```
<input type="text" name="dateOfBirith" id="dob" class="bootstrap-datepicker form-control tempDateFrom" data-date-format="mm-dd-yy">
```

[image: When does not pull data from database]

```
<input type="text" name="dateOfBirith" id="dob"  value="${employee.dateOfBirith}" class="bootstrap-datepicker form-control tempDateFrom" data-date-format="mm-dd-yy">
```

[image]

Comment: Which datepicker plugin are you using?

Comment: `data-date-format="mm-dd-yy">` vs `2017-12-31`

Comment: Try changing your date-date-format according to what you get from database and it should work then